# Uploading image to google drive in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I tried to upload image to my drive in python
and I got that in output
Image with ID `'1ZWfY4n473bD58RpqSX-HBeb8H6pa63bc'` was uploaded to the folder with ID 'your_folder_id' on Google Drive

but when i goto my drive i didnt find anything.

sample of code:

Set up authentication by loading the client_secrets.json file and creating a credentials object:

```
creds = None
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'agricultureproject.json', scopes=SCOPES)
```

Create a function to upload the image to Google Drive:

```
def upload_image_to_drive(image_url, folder_id):
    try:
        # Create a Drive API client
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        file_metadata = {'name': 'IdentityDiagram.PNG'}
        media = MediaFileUpload('IdentityDiagramPNG.PNG', mimetype='image/jpeg')
    # Upload the image to Google Drive
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

    print(f"Image with ID '{file.get('id')}' was uploaded to the folder with ID '{folder_id}' on Google Drive")

except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
    file = None

return file
```

Call the upload_image_to_drive function with the URL of the image you want to upload and the ID of the folder you want to upload it to:

```
folder_id = 'your_folder_id'
image_url = 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/9e391b9c-462a-4ca6-8832-5e56159f999d_1.aedccea75551f143d7ab991716ec8e05.jpeg'
upload_image_to_drive(image_url, folder_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.  First being your create

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'IdentityDiagram.PNG'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('IdentityDiagramPNG.PNG', mimetype='image/jpeg')

    # Upload the image to Google Drive
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

You have not set a parent directory there for the file is going into the root folder of the currently authenticated user.

Your second issue is that you have forgotten that a service account is not you.  You have uploaded the file to the root directory owned by the service account.

Do a file.list and you will see that the file was uploaded to the service accounts google drive account.

Finally note remember that the file you upload needs to be on the machine you are uploading from so image_url isnt going to work unless you download the file from the URL first in memory then uploaded it.